# Trying to create family tree in fetching data in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to build up a family tree but having problem in displaying data.

I have two tables as followed:-

tbl_member_info (For storing member details) -

```
**1 member_id (this column is child_id in another table tbl_relationship)**
2   relationship_name
3   biological_relation
4   prefix
5   suffix
6   status
7   gender
8   email
9   dob_option
10  dob_one
11  dob_two
12  native_place
13  current_location
14  occupation
15  created_on
16  first_name
17  last_name
```

tbl_relationship (For mapping relationship data with parent id):-

```
1   relationship_unique_id
2   user_id
3   parent_id (member who is creating the relatives)
**4 child_id**
```

Now the thing is I am able to insert the data, but unable to fetch it properly.

Can anyone guide me through this.

Thanks

Comment: Create few scenario for your desired output, then it will be easier for us to guide.

Comment: //select all family data
$getFamilyData = $this->family_model->getFamilyData($userId);
foreach($getFamilyData as $data)
{  
            //var_dump($data);
            $parent_id = $data->parent_id;
            $getChildData = $this->family_model->getChildData($parent_id);
            print_r($getChildData);exit;
            
   
}
exit;
I have get the parent data and child data how to store in multidimension and display in viw in tree format

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using join query quite easily.

1. At first, found out parents. (like this - `Select user_id where parent_id = ""`)
2. Then found out children's data for each parent using another query. When calling this method, send parents_id using `foreach` & your previously return data. Store it in a multidimensional array & return it to controller, display as per your requirements.

Comment: //select all family data
        $getFamilyData = $this->family_model->getFamilyData($userId);
        foreach($getFamilyData as $data)
        {  
            //var_dump($data);
            $parent_id = $data->parent_id;
            $getChildData = $this->family_model->getChildData($parent_id);
            print_r($getChildData);exit;
            
   
        }
        exit;

Comment: //select all family data
$getFamilyData = $this->family_model->getFamilyData($userId);
foreach($getFamilyData as $data)
{  
            //var_dump($data);
            $parent_id = $data->parent_id;
            $getChildData = $this->family_model->getChildData($parent_id);
            print_r($getChildData);exit;
            
   
}
exit;
I have get the parent data and child data how to store in multidimension and display in viw in tree format

Comment: your question is not clear. want to know how to store data in multidimensional array? if yes, then this will be the format - $data['parent1']['child1'], about tree format - at first display all parents horizontally using css & then print children of each parents below it using your collected info.

Comment: Thanks, i am confused in one thing

Comment: This is the url in which surname and parent id is coming:-

$url = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="assign_val('.$surname.','.$data->parent_id.');" style="color: blue;">[+]&nbsp;Add Relative</a>';
 
Output of this url is 

assign_val(Awasthi,52);

I want the output like:-

assign_val('Awasthi','52');

Comment: add single quote before your variable inside double quote like this "'".$surname."'", hope it will work. Another thing, you have not accept my answer. ;(

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="assign_val(" awasthi","awasthi");"="" style="color: blue;">[+]&nbsp;Add Relative</a>

Comment: Use escape character or single quote at first time for this portion "assign_val(" awasthi","awasthi");"="" style="color: blue;"